# ERRO Connection lost due to: EOF benthos stream

Tags: go, stream, eof, benthos

I am going to stream static Benthos but when I stream a single file it works fine. but when try to stream 2 files it gives `EOF` error.

Here is the error screenshot.
[image]

below are the files.

bar.yaml

```
input:
  opcuatrigger:
    endpoint: "opc.tcp://localhost:46010"
    nodeIDs: ["ns=2;s=Humidity", "ns=2;s=Air Quality"]
    subscribeEnabled: true
    insecure: true
pipeline:
  processors:
    - bloblang: |
        root = meta("Message").parse_json()
        root.value = this
        root.timestamp_ms = (timestamp_unix_nano() / 1000000).floor()
output:
  mqtt:
    urls:
      - 'localhost:1883'
    topic: 'ia/raw/opcuatrigger${! meta("opcua_path") }'
    client_id: benthos-umh
```

foo.yaml

```
input:
  opcua:
    endpoint: "opc.tcp://localhost:46010"
    nodeIDs: ["ns=2;s=Humidity", "ns=2;s=Air Quality"]
    subscribeEnabled: true
    insecure: true
pipeline:
  processors:
    - bloblang: |
        root.value = this
        root.timestamp_ms = (timestamp_unix_nano() / 1000000).floor()
output:
  mqtt:
    urls:
      - 'localhost:1883'
    topic: 'ia/raw/opcua/'
    client_id: benthos-umh
```

use below command for it.

```
benthos streams ./streams/*.yaml
```

using [benthos-umh](https://github.com/united-manufacturing-hub/benthos-umh) for plugin

Comment: Hey @Girish Bhutiya, I don't have enough information here to reproduce this issue you're seeing. The first thing to check is if `ia/raw/opcuatrigger${! meta("opcua_path") }` resolves to the topic you expect via a `log` processor. If that's correct, then maybe try replacing the `opcua` input with `generate` and check if you have the same problem. If yes, please try to reproduce it with the `ncarlier/mqtt` Docker container or similar and share the setup.

Comment: Yes issue in MQTT and I have fixed it via added redis in output and it is fixed. Thanks for your help.